# Strip down the amount of layout xml required in an app

Tags: android, xml, layout

Lets say I want to create an Android app which shows a list consisting names of 200 people on the main activity. When users clicking on any name, they are taken to a screen showing the available info about that person. The details about each person may vary(some don't have an address, etc).

How will I tackle the issue of 201 different layout files(xml)?

I don't think it will be a good idea to make 201 activities.

If I use Fragments then I'll have to make 200 xml as well as 201 java files(for each different fragment).

If I use layout inflater or view switcher, even then I'll have to make 201 xmls.

So is there a way to strip down the number of layouts that will be required?

Comment: If I get you right, I would just use a listview with custom Layout http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html and a activity/fragment with all necessary views (fill them programmatically with textViewName.setText(user.getName()) and hide those views where you do not have data `if(user.getZipCode() == null) textViewZip.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the layouts for each of the person different aside from the data e.g. address, name, etc. changing? Because if they aren't different you can use the same layout for each one of those people and just load the corresponding data of each person. If you can give me more information about how you store your data and how you display it I can give you a better answer.

Comment: The layouts are different but they might have one or more widget(TextView, etc) in common. Also the OnClickListner of the buttons(if any) will execute different actions.

Comment: Well maybe if you explain a little better what the actual differences are I can help you further.

Comment: Lets say the first person is a human so the layout will consist:
Name(TextView)
Address(TextView)
Phone(TextView)
Call(Button)

Now the second person is a zombie, so the layout goes:
Name(TextView)
Space Ship Number(TextView)
Ping(Button)

As you can see the two layouts have a common TextView 'Name', but the action performed by the Call button for a human won't be the same as the Ping button for a zombie.

Comment: For the layout it does not matter what the buttons do. You can create one layout with all possible Views inside it. Views you need are set to visible and views you don't need are set to gone. You can load the texts in the TextViews and Buttons dynamically depending on the type and identity of the person whose data you want to display. And the click listeners also can do different things depending on what you want to display. If it's not possible to generalize it that far you can still create a layout for humans, than a different one for zombies etc.

Comment: Okay, the answer is almost complete but, (1) If I load an xml with 1000 views inside(say, 10 are visible) would the rest 990 which are invisible impact performance?

(2) Are you suggesting to use a switch statement inside the ClickListener to perform different things depending on what I want to display?

Comment: You should never have a layout with so many different views. Why do you think that would be necessary? And yes a switch statement in the click listeners is exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need that many files at all. In fact, all you need is your main screen containing the list of people, and then a screen containing the placeholder of the details.

When the user is clicked (presumably from some sort of listview) you can pass the details related to that user into the details activity where you can display it nicely, so reusing the same class/activity/layout.

This is a good tutorial showing you the basical mechanism of passing information between activities.

http://www.javabeat.net/how-to-transfer-data-between-activities-in-android/

Comment: The layouts are different(thats what my question is).